# Untar on Solaris 9 : longlink

Tags: tar, solaris

I'm trying to install MySQL on a solaris 9 machine, and the version of `tar` on this machine apparently can't handle larger file names.  The solution I've found from googling involves downloading GNU tar for solaris 9 from sunfreeware.com.  However, all of their packages for solaris 9 have been moved to unixpackages.com, which requires a subscription for downloads.

Do I have any free options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just compile your own. Most GNU software is pretty easy to compile. For example:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

is the standard incantation. You may want to set a different install directory (maybe under your homedir) using the `--prefix` option. Run `./configure --help` to see all the options.

Comment: Yay.  I wonder why none of the tutorials or forums I saw suggested that.